# SQL Server can't retrieve status of snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent

I'm running SQL Server 2012, and for some strange reason I'm unable to run snapshots to enable a replication process. My server can't retrieve the status of the snapshot agent and I get this error after a few minutes

> Could not retrieve agent status.
>   (Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:840), database ID 30. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider))